# Show that $|u(x)|\leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(I)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open bounded interval. Show that any $u\in W^{1,p}(I)$ satisfies $|u(x)|\leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(I)}$, where $C>0$ is independent of $u$.

I don't have a lot of high powered inequalities to work with, other than Holder or Minkowski (Young's inequality is probably OK).

I know by FTC that $$u(x) = \int_y^x u'(t) \, dt+u(y).$$ We also have the definition of $\|u\|^p_{W^{1,p}}=\|u\|_{L^p}^p+\|u'\|^p_{L^p}$

And finally we also know (by Minkowski) that for any functions in $L^P(I)$ we have $\|f+g\|_p\leq\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p,$ and that $|a+b|^p\leq 2^p(a^p+b^p)$, and thus $\|f+g\|_p^p\leq(\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p)^p\leq2^p(\|f\|_p^p+\|g\|_p^p)$

I feel like these are the right ingredients to prove the needed result, but I'm struggling to see how I should put them together.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the fundamental theorem, we get (putting absolute values everywhere and enlarge integration region from $(x,y)$ to $I$)
$$
|u(x)| \le \left| \int_y^x u'(t)dt + u(y)\right| \le \int_y^x |u'(t)|dt +|
 u(y)| \le \int_I |u'|dt + |u(y)|.
$$
Let $L$ be the length of the interval.
Now integrate with respect to $y$:
$$
L|u(x)| \le   \int_I L |u'| + |u| dt \le \max(1,L) \int_I  |u'| + |u| dt .
$$
In that way, the left-hand side contains the evaluation in $x$, where on the right-hand side we only have integrals.
This proves the claim for $p=1$. Apply Hoelder inequality to get the estimate for $p>1$.

Comment: To add for the OP, you do need to justify the fundamental theorem of calculus can be applied to $u \in W^{1,p}(I),$ and that pointwise values $u(x)$ make sense. Of course this is fine as $W^{1,p}(I) \subset AC(I),$ but from first principles a density argument is probably easier.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed reply; I've been on the road the last few days.
I follow the solution you gave, but I'm hung up on two minor points.

1) after you say "integrate with respect to y" it looks like you integrate with respect to $t$ instead. Was there a typo there?

2) After I get to the inequality you have, my final answer is still of the form $|u(x)|\leq\int_I|u'|dt+\frac{1}{L}\int_I|u| dy$. The second term has the $\frac{1}{L}$ factor in it, and so I don't actually obtain something proportional to the $W_{1,p}$ norm. I feel like I'm missing something really simple here.

Comment: See edit. Hope this helps

Comment: Ahh. Right. That helps a lot. Thanks for your help!